# Puzzling High School - Two Days until Prom

Tags: logical-deduction

**Puzzling High School:**
Puzzling High School is tied up in knots right now. It's two days until prom and no one has sorted anything out yet! Every one of the 20 students at the school (it's a small school) are in love with at least one other student and has at least one other student in love with them... and there are no cases of mutual attraction.

Except as noted, each student loves only one other student; no student is loved by more than two others. There are no outside characters.

- Alice (Straight Female): Loved by someone who is loved by Erica.
- Bob (Straight Male): Loved by Queenie; loves someone who loves Frank.
- Cindy (Straight Female): Loved by someone who is loved by Alice.
- David (Gay Male): Loved by two girls (those poor fools).
- Erica (Bisexual Female): Loves Nelson and a straight girl; the girl loves David.
- Frank (Straight Male): Loves a girl who loves two other students.
- Gloria (Straight Female): Loves a bisexual guy who loves one girl.
- Hank (Straight Male): Loves two girls, one of whom loves Indigo.
- Indigo (Straight Female): Loves a guy who loves Patrick.
- Jack (Bisexual Male): Loves Megan, loved by two girls.
- Katie (Lesbian Female): Loves someone who loves Jack.
- Lucas (Straight Male): Loves Katie, unlike everyone else.
- Megan (Straight Female): Loves two guys, one of whom loves Katie.
- Nelson (Bisexual Male): Loves a guy and a girl; the girl loves Roger.
- Olivia (Bisexual Female): Loves the same student as Gloria; not loved by Katie.
- Patrick (Straight Male): Loved by David, loves someone who loves Jack.
- Queenie (Straight Female): Loved by someone who also loves Erica.
- Roger (Straight Male): Loves someone who loves Hank.
- Sally (Straight Female): Loved by Tim; doesn't love Frank.
- Tim (Bisexual Male): Loved by someone who loves someone else.

*Can you figure out who loves who?*

Comment: "each student loves only one other student" and Nelson "Loves a guy and a girl". Is this intentional? It seems contradictory.

Comment: @AustinWeaver It says "_Except as noted_, each student loves only one other student" so I think Nelson, Megan, Hank, and Erica are the exceptions to that rule.

Comment: @Aces That's exactly it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I have a solution -

> N->A->R
>  Q->B->M
>  R->C->H
>  I,S->D->P
>  F,H->E
>  M->F->E
>  K->G->J
>  C->H->E,Q
>  E->I->D
>  G,O->J->M
>  L->K->G
>  B,J->M->L,F
>  E->N->A,T
>  P->O->J
>  D->P->O
>  H->Q->B
>  A->R->C
>  T->S->D
>  N->T->S

EDIT by OP:

> Alice: Loves Roger
>  Bob: Loves Megan
>  Cindy: Loves Hank
>  David: Loves Patrick
>  Erica: Loves Indigo and Nelson
>  Frank: Loves Erica
>  Gloria: Loves James
>  Hank: Loves Queenie and Erica
>  Indigo: Loves David
>  Jack: Loves Megan
>  Katie: Loves Gloria
>  Lucas: Loves Katie
>  Megan: Loves Lucas and Frank
>  Nelson: Loves Alice and Tim
>  Olivia: Loves James
>  Patrick: Loves Olivia
>  Queenie: Loves Bob
>  Roger: Loves Cindy
>  Sally: Loves David
>  Tim: Loves Sally

Comment: Alright, after picking apart your listing, you've got it all right.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm trying to fix it. Do you know how to make a multi line spoiler?

Comment: Just wait for the peer review. I already sent in the edit. In general, put two spaces at the end of each line.